# Initialize to nested screen with back button to stack root in react-native using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using React Native and the React-Navigation library to replicate the nav behavior in the iOS Reddit app Apollo: https://i.imgur.com/983G04Q.png

My routing structure is as follows:

```
TabNavigation
|- PostsTab
  |- PostsStack
    |- SubredditListScreen
    |- PostFeedScreen
    |- PostDetailsScreen
```

I want to achieve the following:

- When the app starts, the user sees the `PostFeedScreen`.
- The `PostFeedScreen` has a "Back" button in its header that navigates to the `SubredditListScreen`.
- If the `PostsTab` tab bar is pressed when on `PostFeedScreen`, scroll to the top, and if already at the top, navigate to the `SubredditListScreen`.
- The `SubredditListScreen` doesn't have a back button, but the user can drag from the right-edge to return to the `PostFeedScreen`.

This is the code I have:

```
// TabNavigation.tsx

function TabNavigation() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name={SCREENS.POSTS} component={PostsStackScreen} />
      // ..other non-relevant tabs
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

// PostsStackScreen.tsx

function PostsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <PostsStack.Navigator initialRouteName={SCREENS.POSTS_FEED}>
      <PostsStack.Screen name={SCREENS.SUBREDDITS_LIST} component={SubredditsScreen} />
      <PostsStack.Screen name={SCREENS.POSTS_FEED} component={PostFeedScreen} />
      <PostsStack.Screen name={SCREENS.POST_DETAILS} component={PostDetailsScreen} />
    </PostsStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

However, my code doesn't work as expected:

- The app correctly initializes to the `PostFeedScreen`, but there is no "Back" button to the `Subreddits` screen.
- Clicking the tab button doesn't take the user to the `Subreddits` screen.

How can I accomplish the above with React-Navigation?
Thank you!